# Json Diff Patch Javascript - extjs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, git, extjs

Well I put my great effort to solve my problem so in the end I finally end up here posting a question

I want to show my JSON diff like this in the given link below
https://neil.fraser.name/software/diff_match_patch/svn/trunk/demos/demo_diff.html

Here is the documentation of the given Library
https://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/

Any one have idea how to used it an Sencha Extjs to display diff between two JSON objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-diff

We use it - it's great - example:

```
var diff = require('deep-diff').diff;

var lhs = {
    name: 'my object',
    description: 'it\'s an object!',
    details: {
        it: 'has',
        an: 'array',
        with: ['a', 'few', 'elements']
    }
};

var rhs = {
    name: 'updated object',
    description: 'it\'s an object!',
    details: {
        it: 'has',
        an: 'array',
        with: ['a', 'few', 'more', 'elements', { than: 'before' }]
    }
};

var differences = diff(lhs, rhs);
```

Comment: What do you use to patch the diff?

Answer (score 5):

you might want to look at [jsondiffpatch](https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch) (disclaimer: I'm the author),

you can [try it online here](http://benjamine.github.io/jsondiffpatch/demo/index.html),
just some highlights:

- a smart array diff (uses [LCS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem) to detect adds/removes, and finds item moved in arrays)
- it's pretty customizable, you can even write plugins to change any part of diff/patch mechanism
- if 2 long strings are found anywhere in the graph, it will use the Neil Fraser's lib you mention internally to get a text unidiff
- multiple formatters, html (the one used at the online demo), console, annotated, and now jsonpatch (RFC6902)

this should work for diffing/patching any 2 objects, framework agnostic, if ExtJS defines special private properties on your objects, you can ignore them specifying a `propertyFilter`

Comment: @MoxShah sorry it's a javascript library. it can generate html (see https://github.com/benjamine/jsondiffpatch/blob/master/docs/formatters.md#html ).
from c# maybe you can use CLI interface, as a node subprocess (has a performance cost), or if you feel very adventurous, use Managed JScript to stay in the .net VM.